# Select rows if the two column values are identical else select another combination in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have following table in PostgreSQL. For each id of a trial_id, I would like to keep those rows where name_split = digest_part_matched. If For an id of a trial_id, name_split = digest_part_matched condition is not met, I would like to keep those rows where name_split = normalized_name, if it exists.

```
id          trial_id    intervention_name                                           name_split                             digest_part_matched  normalized_name code
98262908855 NCT02582996 acetaminophen                                               acetaminophen                          acetaminophen        acetaminophen   A
98262908855 NCT02582996 acetaminophen                                               acetaminophen                          (null)               acetaminophen    B
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    acetaminophen                          dihydroergotamine    acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.  C
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    acetaminophen                          acetaminophen        acetaminophen   D
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    caffeine                               caffeine acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.   E1
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    caffeine                               caffeine acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.   E2
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    dihydroergotamine                      dihydroergotamine    acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.  F
98262908902 NCT02582996 metoclopramide.+dihydroergotamine                           dihydroergotamine                      metoclopramide.  dihydroergotamine  F
```

The desired output is:

```
id          trial_id    intervention_name   name_split  digest_part_matched normalized_name
98262908855 NCT02582996 acetaminophen       acetaminophen   acetaminophen   acetaminophen  A
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    acetaminophen   acetaminophen   acetaminophen   D
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    caffeine    caffeine    acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.   E1
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    caffeine    caffeine    acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.   E2
98262908901 NCT02582996 acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.    dihydroergotamine   dihydroergotamine   acetaminophen+caffeine+dihydroergotamine+metoclopramide.  F
98262908902 NCT02582996 metoclopramide.+dihydroergotamine                           dihydroergotamine                      metoclopramide.  dihydroergotamine  F
```

I am trying following query.

```
select distinct on (id, trial_id) * from tbl
where name_split = digest_part_matched
```

Answer (score 0):

`distinct on` can do this. I think you want:

```
select distinct on (id, trial_id) * 
from tbl
where name_split in (digest_part_matched, normalized_name)
order by 
    id, 
    trial_id,
    (name_split = digest_part_matched) desc
```

The third expression in the `order by` clause gives piority to rows where `name_split` matches on `digest_part_matched`.

You do not specify what to do with `(id, trial_id)` tuples where there is none of the two columns ever matches `name_split`. The above query will just eliminate them. The query can easliy be adapted to retain one row per such group of rows, provided that you have another criteria to decide which row should be retained:

```
select distinct on (id, trial_id) * 
from tbl
order by 
    id, 
    trial_id,
    (name_split = digest_part_matched) desc,
    (name_split = normalized_name) desc,
    -- another criteria here
```

Comment: In case, I would like to retain those rows where there is none of the two columns matches name_split, how can I do that..?

Comment: (name_split != digest_part_matched) desc,
    (name_split != normalized_name) desc,  works?

Comment: @rshar: this is explained at the end of my answer...

Comment: The query works, however it is unable to deal with those rows where multiple matches exists. eg. where name_split = 'caffeine'. distinct on keeps only one row